# How to generate random numbers from a array whose sum is N (Not Defined) in Android Java?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have a specific range in an array.

```
 private int[] arr = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6};
```

I've successfully generated the numbers up to the sum, but the random numbers are not in my array range.

```
 private ArrayList<Integer> random(int targetSum, int numberOfDraws) {
        Random r = new Random();
        ArrayList<Integer> load = new ArrayList<>();

        //random numbers
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDraws; i++) {
            int next = r.nextInt(targetSum) + 1;
            load.add(next);
            sum += next;
        }

        //scale to the desired target sum
        double scale = 1d * targetSum / sum;
        sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDraws; i++) {
            load.set(i, (int) (load.get(i) * scale));
            sum += load.get(i);
        }

        //take rounding issues into account
        while (sum++ < targetSum) {
            int i = r.nextInt(numberOfDraws);
            load.set(i, load.get(i) + 1);
        }

        return load;
    }
```

Where I'm making a mistake? What new solution should I improve?

Comment: What do you mean by "*the random numbers are not in my array range*"?  What would the right result look like?

Comment: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6}  random number must be one of these

Comment: What is "*random*" about them?

Comment: let me be clear, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6} I want to pick up any number from this array

Comment: Indexes in this array go from 0 to 5. All you need is to generate random integers from 0 to 5.  Do you know how to do it?

Comment: I know how to do it, but also I want to calculate the total using these numbers.

For example,

The total is 11.

that should be 1+4+3+1+0+2 = 11.

Comment: You either calculate the total of randomly selected array elements or pick array elements to get a predefined total.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210030/discussion-between-pranav-fulkari-and-pm-77-1).